# Как динамически (через FOR, или foreach) наполнить datagridview столбцами и строками?

Tags: c#, ado.net

коллеги.
У меня имеются две таблицы, customers и orders. между ними реализована связь 1 к 1 по полю 'CustomerNo'.
Мне нужно вывести datagridview, в котором следует вывести статистику продаж по городам. Поле 'City' находится в таблице customers. поле продажи - есть новый столбец, который считает вхождение CustomerNo в таблицу orders. Надеюсь доступно объяснил. В консольном приложении сделал, всё получилось, а вот теперь то же самое вывести в datagridview не могу.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=WKS456\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ShopDB;Integrated Security=True";
        string commandString = "SELECT City, CustomerNo FROM Customers; SELECT * FROM Orders;";
        DataSet shopDB = new DataSet("ShopDB");
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(commandString, connectionString);
        adapter.Fill(shopDB);
        DataTable Customers = shopDB.Tables[0];
        DataTable Orders = shopDB.Tables[1];
        shopDB.Relations.Add("Customers_Orders", Customers.Columns["CustomerNo"], Orders.Columns["CustomerNo"]);
        Customers.Columns.Add("CountSale", typeof(double), "Count(Child(Customers_Orders).CustomerNo)");
        foreach (DataRow customer in Customers.Rows)
        {
            if (customer.GetChildRows("Customers_Orders").Length != 0)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(customer[0]);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", customer[0], customer[2]);
                Console.WriteLine();

           }
        }
```

Как теперь вывести динамический datagridview через циклы, чтобы автоматически заполнилось количество столбцов, присвоить их имена из datatable, и строки наполнились данными. Большое спасибо всем, кто отзовётся!

[image: Структура БД]

Comment: Вы точно уверено что связь 1-к-1? Может всё такие покупатели могут иметь несколько заказов? Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе структуру БД. Чтобы редактировать вопрос воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править".

Comment: @Anamnian, поправил

Comment: а обязательно использование циклов?

Comment: @Monomax, Ну я просто хотел чтобы столбцы подтянулись динамически, а потом строками наполнялась таблица  в данные столбцы. Кстати я уже сам решил задачу.